# Explicitly wait for element that is the child of another element

Tags: python, selenium

If you have a WebElement object, you can search through its children like this

```
element = WebElement(blah...)
element.find_element_by_id('blah')
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using an explicit wait, as in

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout)
element = wait.until(expectedCondition(locator))
```

So rather than searching through the whole DOM, how can I specify that the *explicit wait* should search only an element's children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With python, `until` actually just calls the method against the driver it is passed. Because of this, and the fact that most driver methods are also webelement methods, you can actually pass the webelement as the 'driver' to WebDriverWait.

So for your example:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(webelement, self.timeout)
element = wait.until(expectedCondition(locator))
```

Alternatively, you can just use a lambda:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout)
element = wait.until(lambda d: webelement.find_element_by_id('blah'))
```

Comment: Can I do the same in Java?

Comment: I am confused, you never reference the `d` parameter in the body of the lambda? Where is `webelement` coming from?