# Selenium wait for presence of nested element query

Tags: python, selenium

In Selenium you can wait for a DOM element to load using `WebDriverWait` and `EC.presence_of_element()`

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))
```

However, this queries the entire DOM. This does not suit scenarios where you have multiple `button`'s on the the page and are querying for a specific one. The `presence_of_element_located()` will trigger on the first instance of a `button`

```html
<body>
    <div class="sign-in">
        <button>Sign In!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button>play!</button> <!-- The button we care about-->
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to perform a `WebDriverWait` for a the `button` inside of `.controls` specifically

Selenium allows you to perform nested queries by chaining `.find_element()`

```py
control_button = driver.find_element(
    By.CLASS_NAME, 'controls').find_element(
        By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
```

is there a comparable technique for `presence_of_element()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Using `By.CSS_SELECTOR`

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.controls button')))
```

#### Solution 2

Passing the parent `WebElement` as the driver to the `WebDriverWait()`

```py
controls = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'controls')

WebDriverWait(controls, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))
```

Related:

- [Selenium - wait until presence of child element of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43312955/12574341)
- [Explicitly wait for element that is the child of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42615967/12574341)